# why does this box shadow not disappear when set to 0px 0px 0px 0px

Tags: css

im making a dark theme for a school-required website and can't seem to remove [this box shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trom7.png) (i know this is part of its element simply because if I do  `visibility: hidden;` the shadow goes away along with the box)
my current code is at

```css
tbody .courserow-info {
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px orange;
}
.zoom-btn {
    background-color: #18113d;
}
.container-fluid {
height: 100%;    
background-color: #2c2f33;
}
.left,.right{ visibility: hidden;}
.left .nav-button-container {
     visibility:visible;
}
    .object-selector .btn {
        
    }
.app-body {
    background-color: #2c2f33;
} 
.project,
.power .default,
.additional .default,
.challenge .default {
    background-color: #45568e;
    color: #dddddd;
}
.danger.focusarea-list-item-content,
.project.danger 
{
    background-color: #443535;
}
```

(the element in question is tbody .courserow-info)

 I have tried setting box shadow to none, I have tried raising the z-index of the course area and I have tried setting the color

Comment: I believe you need to set box-shadow: none;

Comment: i have already tried that... maybe i could add a div that covers it up?

Comment: What kind of selector adds the shadow in the first place? Try `box-shadow: none !important;` as a *temporary* measure; if it works, you need to adjust your selectors so the right rule takes precedence with regard to `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't posted HTML, so I can't test but I believe it needs an important rule to be applied.
Try

```
tbody .courserow-info {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: its not my HTML